# convert byte and float to char

Tags: arduino-uno, web

I am trying to send sensor values to internet via enc28j60 module and web client example.

My problem is that i chose byte and float form for some sensors i can't convert these values to char form.

Code example below

```
UVSensorValue = analogRead(A0);               // UVSensorValue is in byte form
concentration = 1.1*pow(duration,3)-3.8*p...  // concentration is in float form
```

I want to store them in a char variable like this:

> param = "uv=5&temp=23.2&dust=0.62..."

And send them here:

```
ether.browseUrl(PSTR("/measures?"), param, website, browseUrlCallback);
```

I tried strcpy function or String convention but nothing worked. I know its a silly question however i stuck and cant find solution.

If someone could help me i would be pleased. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want [`dtostrf()`](http://www.microchip.com/webdoc/AVRLibcReferenceManual/group__avr__stdlib_1ga060c998e77fb5fc0d3168b3ce8771d42.html)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In any other C/C++ platform, you can use "%f" as a format specifier when you want to print (or convert to string) a float using `printf` or its siblings. Any, except in Arduino.

To convert a float you need use `dtostrf()`,

```
char * dtostrf(
    double __val,
    signed char __width,
    unsigned char __prec,
    char * __s)
```

> The dtostrf() function converts the double value passed in val into an
>   ASCII representationthat will be stored under s. The caller is
>   responsible for providing sufficient storage in s.
>
> Conversion is done in the format "[-]d.ddd". The minimum field width
>   of the output string (including the possible '.' and the possible sign
>   for negative values) is given in width, and prec determines the number
>   of digits after the decimal sign. width is signed value, negative for
>   left adjustment.
>
> The dtostrf() function returns the pointer to the converted string s.

To convert a byte (or anything not float) to ascii, use `snprintf()`

```
int snprintf ( char * s, 
               size_t n, 
               const char * format, 
               ... );
```

> Write formatted output to sized buffer.
>
> Composes a string with the same
>   text that would be printed if format was used on printf, but instead
>   of being printed, the content is stored as a C string in the buffer
>   pointed by s (taking n as the maximum buffer capacity to fill).

You can read the details by yourself, but here is a demo.

The idea is to produce in `buffer` a traditional C-style string (null terminated). That string you can print or transmit.

The float value is printed in two step. First, we use `dtostrf` to convert the float value to his ascii representation. Then we use `snprintf` to include that value (as a string) inside a whole line, latter to be printed.

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while(!Serial);
  Serial.println("Start");

  float value = 123.45;
  byte balue = 128;

  char buffer[80];
  char fValue[16];
  dtostrf(value, 3, 2, fValue);
  snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "float %s", fValue);
  Serial.println(buffer);
  snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "byte value is %d", (int) balue);
  Serial.println(buffer);
}

void loop() {

}
```

Comment: It helped me achieve it. Thanks a lot man!!